# How to filter on attribute with in XSL matching template tag when it also contains xsi:type attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my xml file:

```
<products>
<product xsi:type="Styles" locale="en_US">
<pageid>abcdef</pageid>
<totalStyles>4</totalStyles>
</product>
<product xsi:type="Styles" locale="en_CA">
<pageid>abcdef</pageid>
<totalStyles>2</totalStyles>
</product>
</products>
```

XSL code:

```
<xsl:template match="products/product">
        <xsl:value-of select="pageid" />
</xsl:template>
```

As listed in the xml file I have two 'product' tags with same pageid, but with different 'locale' values.
I want to filter on the 'locale' and retrieve 'totalStyles' tag value corresponding to only locale=en_US. 
Can someone please suggest me how to modify my template match to filter on the locale value.

Following code works when xsi:type doesn't exits. But, that approach is failing with I have xsi:type component along with locale.

```
<xsl:template match="products/product[@locale='en_US']">
    <xsl:value-of select="totalStyles"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance.

Sorry if I didn't form the question properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used following logic to filter on attribute value:

```
<xsl:template match="products/product">
<xsl:if test="@locale='en_US'">

      "Process Record"

</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="products/product[@locale='en_US']">
    <xsl:value-of select="totalStyles"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Your code works if the product doesn't have 'xsi:type="Styles" parameter. But if 'product' contains both xsi:type and locale params then the filter is not working. Any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: @Ruk16 you did not mention the `'xsi:type` in your question. Why should it not match when this attribute is present. Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have now edited the question. I tried various approaches, but could not find why having xsi:type attribute is causing issues.